# No arguments allowed error on implicit class method

Tags: scala

I'm trying to <strike>cram</strike> brush up on Scala for a job I got, and I'm looking into implicit classes. So far they seem quite handy in making code more readable, but I've run into a problem that I can't figure out.

In this code, I'm implementing some common vector operations, and for the most part they seem to be running just fine. However, when I added the `norm` method, the `magn` method started throwing errors. My operating script is thus:

```
import scala.language.postfixOps

import scala.math.sqrt
case class Vector(x: Double, y: Double)
object VMath {
  implicit class VectorMath(v1: Vector) {
    def dot(v2: Vector): Double = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y
    def cross(v2: Vector): Double = v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x
    def magn(): Double = sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y)
    def norm(): Vector = Vector(v1.x / magn, v1.y / magn)
  }
}

import VMath._

val a = Vector(1.0, 2.0)
val b = Vector(3.0, 4.0)
a dot b
a cross b
a magn
a norm
```

Whenever I run this code, the line `a magn` throws an error that reads

```
no arguments allowed for nullary method magn: ()Double
```

It had no problem running before I implemented the `norm` method, and it has no problems *within* the `norm` method. I'm not sure if this is due to my misunderstanding of how Scala itself works, how `postfixObs` works, how implicit classes work, how single line methods work, or if it's just some stupid typo that I'm missing, but this has got me tearing my hair out. (And I happen to like my hair, so...)

My code can be tested and the problem recreated on Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0jvrx4lYQwauBpN6IZtSPA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix notation (dot-less) **can** be used when the method takes no argument, but you have to help the compiler figure it out.

```
a magn

a norm;
```

A blank line, or a semicolon, tells the compiler to stop looking for the argument to pass to the method. It's not coming.

It's usually better to reserve dot-less notation for only the simplest, most obvious, declarations (with all 3 pieces).

Answer (score 4):

Seems like compiler got confused and treated `a` in the last line as argument to `magn` method. There is nothing wrong with your implementation of `norm` method.

Possible fixes

- add dots -> `a.magn`
- terminate line with semicolon `a magn;`
- introduce empty paranthesis `a magn()`